# select data from database and get right order after grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT chat.*, user.vorname AS vorname, user.images AS userImage, nachrichten.ID as lastMessageID FROM `chat` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON chat.userID = user.ID 
LEFT JOIN `nachrichten` ON chat.chatToken = nachrichten.chatToken
WHERE chat.userID != 1 AND chat.chatToken = chat.chatToken
ORDER BY nachrichten.ID DESC
```

The Output:

[image]

Now I would like to group the result by userID:

```
SELECT chat.*, user.vorname AS vorname, user.images AS userImage, nachrichten.ID as lastMessageID FROM `chat` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON chat.userID = user.ID 
LEFT JOIN `nachrichten` ON chat.chatToken = nachrichten.chatToken
WHERE chat.userID != 1 AND chat.chatToken = chat.chatToken
GROUP BY chat.userID
ORDER BY nachrichten.ID DESC
```

The result:

[image]

But I get the lowest "lastMessageID" - I would like to get the highest ID

Dennis -> 97 (instead of 90)

Where is my fault?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add where the data is coming from

Comment: try: SELECT ....., MAX(lastMessageID) ........

Comment: @BerndBuffen : Thats it !! Thanks :)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the `id` of the latest message per user. If so, I would recommend a correlated subquery rather than aggregation:

```
select 
    c.*, 
    u.vorname, 
    u.images as userimage, 
    (select max(n.id) from `nachrichten` n where n.chatToken = c.chatToken) as lastmessageid 
from `chat` c 
inner join `user` u on u.id = c.userid
where c.userid != 1
```

This query would work on any version of MySQL, including 5.7 or higher, where `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled by default (which would cause your original query to fail, since the `SELECT` clause contains non-aggregated columns that do not belong to the `GROUP BY` clause).

Side notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- I removed irrelevant condition `chat.chatToken = chat.chatToken` from the `where` clause; if your itent is to eliminate rows where `chat.chatToken` is `null`, just use `c.chatToken is not null`